# What is this larger gun indication on the minimap?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds, mobile

Something in PUBG Mobile, on my minimap, I see a bullet indication. This means that a gunshot can be heard from the direction it's pointing.

However sometimes, I get this larger indicator that points in the general direction. What type of gun is this gunshot? Is it a suppressor on a gun?

Edit: If this helps, I was playing the **Mini Zone** mode.

Here is a screenshot I managed to get during game play.***(Look at the minimap)***
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this image below, its "gunshot from firearms with muffler:"

[image]

The image comes from a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/PUBGMobile/comments/7zpygw/could_anyone_translate_these_indicators/) discussing this.

Comment: You mean a suppressor right?

Comment: @GamerM that is almost certainly what they mean by the word muffler. The icon looks a lot like one.